# Subprocess in tkinter, running .exe file

Tags: python, tkinter

My code:

```
import subprocess

for file in ('folder_with_all_files'):
  a= subprocess.Popen(['my_exe_file.exe',file,'command'],shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)\ communicate()[0]
```

Normally in `.py` script all goes fine. but when i am trying to put those lines in `tkinter`, nothing happens.

Part of `Tkinter` code:

```
 def Run():
      for file in ('folder_with_all_files'):
        a= subprocess.Popen(['my_exe_file.exe',file,'command'],shell=True, 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)\ communicate()[0]


    button.configure(command=RUN)
```

What i am doing wrong? and how to choose only specific extension of files that i want to use, example : .dat only
Thanks

EDIT: i have also tried:

```
def Run():
  filenames=os.listdir('folder_with_all_files') 
  for file in filenames:
    a= subprocess.Popen(['my_exe_file.exe',file,'command'],shell=True, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)\ communicate()[0]
```

even when i am adding direct path to file doesnt work

```
a= subprocess.Popen(['my_exe_file.exe','direct path/file','command']
```

but still doesnt work

Comment: `for file in ('folder_with_all_files'):` will run your command once for `f`, once for `o`, once for `l`, and so on - you're iterating over the characters of a string.

Comment: @jasonharper please take a look on my edit post

Answer (score 1):

Problem was connected with files, i was showing only the path to the folder, and program didnt know which files should use.

this line of code helped me to solve the problem, and get specific extension of the files:

```
filenames= glob.glob(os.path.join('path',"*.xxx"))
```

Cheers